# sweetalert - css for input

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

We are using sweetalert and we are trying to style a textbox input but cannot get it to work. See below example the text box is to small for mobile. We can style other buttons and types with the below but cant get text box to style.

```
.swal-button {
  padding: 7px 19px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #3c97d3;
  font-size: 32px;
  border: 1px solid #3e549a;
  text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}


function SaveDesign() {

  swal("Name your design:", {
    icon: "info",
    closeOnClickOutside: false,
    className: "maintext",
    title: "Save your Design",
    content: {
      element: "input",
      attributes: {
        placeholder: "Type your save name"
      }
    }
```

Comment: We tried .swal-input and .swal-content[input] etc

Answer (score 0):

attributes: {
    placeholder: "Type your save name",
    className: "maintext"

I managed to solve it by adding the classname to the attributes section as per above